# Pass lambdas/methods to HandlebarsJS render context

Tags: javascript, lambda, handlebars.js

I see a lot about Handlebar's Handlebars.registerHelper but this seems to be for global helpers.

I instead would like to pass a function to the render context **for each view instance**.

In this particular instance I would like to be able to call my i18n lookup method, which makes use of a variable `localeBase` particular to that instance.

e.g.

```
context = {};
....
context.l = this.lookup;
var html = template(context);
```

and then to be able to call it in the template (not sure of the syntax):

```
The colour of red in french is: {{$l 'colors.red'}}
```

it would be a bonus to be able to pass additional parameters too, for example given a locale string with arguments:

```
Tea is {0}
```

I could do:

```
{{$l 'beverage.tea.opinion' 'wonderful!'}}
```